# How can I solve this problem : hadoop namenode -format gives error?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, hadoop-plugins

I setup Hadoop HA Cluster.

I try to format hadoop as below code:

```
hdfs --loglevel DEBUG namenode -format -force
```

then when I see the log ( it is not DEBUG mode and this is another problem which i ve not solved)
it gives error as below:

```
error org.apacge.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.FileNotFoundException : ..../current/VERSION (Permission denied)
```

When I check the current folder after format , its recreated but with root ownership. And the folder just has **seen_txid** and **VERSION** files.

If I change the ownership (`chown -R hdfs:hadoop ...../current`) , it gives error now as below:

```
 error org.apacge.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
 java.io.FileNotFoundException : no valid image files found
```

because under current folder there is no image file. And i cant see any other logs ( i cant set log level to debug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue ;

1. stop all hdfs services
2. start journal services
3. namenode service (just one)
4. format namenode
5. in **/var/log/hadoop.log** there is warning like (*journal cant be formatted because of file exists*)
6. delete files which reported in the logs
7. format again and it works
8. start other namenodes and hdfs services (zkfc ,datanode .. )